# When do I own an object in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I am new to `Objective-C` and am reading about the memory management guideline. I am a bit confused about the following two statements:

1. You only own an object if you `new`, `alloc`, `retain` and `copy` to create it.
2. When a local variable (a pointer) points to an object, the variable owns the object.

Here is my confusions:

1. What is the difference between "you own the object" and "variable owns the object"? If I create an object via `new/alloc/retain/copy`, I actually create a pointer to point to it so the pointer owns the object. So the two sayings are the same to me.
2. For convenience method, it usually looks like:

   ```
   - (XYZItem *)itemOnTheFly:(id)sender
   {
       XYZItem *item = [[XYZItem alloc] init]; /* Now the object has one owner, *item */

       return item;
   }
   ```

And I call this method:

```
XYZItem *myItem = [XYZItem itemOnTheFly];
```

To my understanding, the object should has one owner, which is `*myItem`. Why some books say that this way `*myItem` doesn't own the object this way? It is still a pointer pointing to an object. A pointer pointing an object should own the object. If *myItem is done with the object, to me, it still needs to release the object. But it seems it is not necessary. If all the code is within autoreleasepool, the pool is the sole owner of the object and will release it automatically. `*myItem` doesn't need to. How can it be like that? If this is the case, then we don't need the strong/weak reference. Put all weak reference into this type of no-ownership-reference and doesn't increase the owner counter of the object!?

Comment: Auto release pools only apply if you call autorelease on the object. Other than that, you should abide by the naming conventions when you're passing ownership of an object out of a method.

Comment: Incidentally, in your example, myItem does indeed own the object, but if your method also stored the object internally and later released it itself, myItem would not own the object (but could still retain&release it if desired, as long as it releases exactly once for each retain). This distinction is undetectable from the method signature, which is why the naming conventions exist.

Comment: Hi Dave, if in the above call, myItem doesn't need to be the owner of the XYZItem object created, how about in another case, say, item is a property of the class and itemOnTheFly is a method of the class? In this case, it is not simply creating an object via convenience method and assign it to a pointer. It becomes assigning the property with the newly created object via its synthesised accessor. In this case, I believe the compiler inserts a retain to make the property an owner of the object. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific rules of ARC; I use manual reference counting. If you have ARC turned on, most retain/release becomes irrelevant. If you have it turned off, the compiler will do nothing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to ARC this was a more important issue --

You "own" an object when it is retained, with no counteracting autorelease pending.  Thus, a method name beginning with "init", "new", "copy", and I think another one I can't remember will return such a "retained object".

The two other categories are "autoreleased" and objects that are "owned" by some other object.

If you do, eg, `[NSArray arrayWithCount:n]`, that returns an autoreleased object.  This means that it's retained, just like the init/new/copy case, but an `autorelease` invocation against it has placed it in a list of objects to be released when you eventually return past an @autorelease block boundary.

On the other hand, if you simply say `myObject = [myArray arrayAtIndex:n];`, that object is neither retained nor autoreleased on your behalf.  Rather, it remains "owned" by the object "myArray", which is sufficient to guarantee it's continued existence (so long as you don't release "myArray" before you've safely stashed "myObject").

As is said, this was all quite important prior to ARC.  With ARC there are ways to get into trouble, but they're considerably more obscure.